# Grub UEFI PXE boot Parted Magic 2013

Tags: grub-efi, pxe

I have setup an Ubuntu Xenial server with `dnsmasq`. I am using `grubnetx64.efi.signed` as the boot image, and have a few things working already. I can pretty much boot any debian based system with `boot=live` as the options. For example clonezilla is working file with:

`# clonezilla
menuentry "Clonezilla" {
location=$configpath/clonezilla_20170220-yakkety
echo "Loading Clonezilla... may take around 2min"
bootoptions="boot=live username=user union=overlay config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset nodmraid locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch=no net.ifnames=0 nosplash noprompt fetch=$tftpserver/$location/filesystem.squashfs"
linux $location/vmlinuz $bootoptions
initrd $location/initrd.img
}`

And debian with:

`# debian 8 standard
menuentry "Debian 8 Standard" {
location=$configpath/debian_8.7.1_standard
echo "Loading Debian 8... may take around 2min"
bootoptions="boot=live components nomodeset fetch=$tftpserver/$location/filesystem.squashfs"
linux $location/vmlinuz $bootoptions
initrd $location/initrd.img
}`

I haven't been able to boot Parted Magic 2013. I have tried:

`# pmagic
menuentry "Partition Magic 2013" {
iso=$configpath/pmagic/pmagic_2013_08_01.iso
echo "Loading Partition Magic... may take around 2min"
loopback loop $iso
linux (loop)/pmagic/bzImage64 iso_filename=$iso boot=live nomodeset
initrd (loop)/pmagic/initrd.img
}`

Which takes A LONG TIME to load and throws the cannot the SQFS file.

And:

`# pmagic
menuentry "Partition Magic 2013" {
location=$configpath/pmagic
echo "Loading Partition Magic... may take around 2min"
bootoptions="edd=on vga=normal"
linux $location/bzImage64 $bootoptions
initrd $location/initrd.img,$location/PMAGIC_2013_11_11.SQFS.cgz
}`

Which again throws the cannot the SQFS file.

Has anyone had any luck booting non debian based distros, specifically pmagic from a Grub PXE Uefi server?